# Qt VirtualKeyboard InputMethod connection to OS

Tags: windows, qt, winapi, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

Qt 5 has strong and complex mechanism to manipulate Virtual Keyboard (Input Method, Input Engine, Input Context) But it works only with Qt applications. How can i connect QtVirtualKeyboard with OS (e.g. Windows 10), to correct working Hunspell in 3rd party applications. Or it's impossible?

Comment: You should file a bug against both hunspell and the programs that use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Qt Virtual Keyboard without Qt.

Comment: No I understand what he meant :D